# What knot should I use to tie the middle of a smaller rope to a large rope?

Tags: climbing, knots, ropes, tree-climbing

I have a spool of smaller 3mm rope that has its end attached to a ball. My intention is to use this smaller line as a throwline that gets thrown over a tree branch which is then used to drag a climbing rope over the branch to anchor it to the branch. Since the smaller rope is conveniently spooled to a rope holder, I'm looking for a knot that I can use to secure the middle of the line (not the end) to the climbing rope. If anyone knows of such a knot, the help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Will that knot and the thrown line be part of your setup when climbing or will they only be used to get the climbing line in place?

Comment: As the larger rope has one free end, you can put a loop in the smaller rope and tie a [bend](https://www.google.co.uk/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=bend+knot).

Comment: ... or just grap a loop of the thin rope with one hand, hold the thin strings together as if a single strand, and tie a simple reef/bow knot with that doubled string, easy to undo.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Weather Vane. I started to think about the problem on my own and came up with the idea of tying a figure eight on a bight and the bend is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Happy you solved it. Aside, please put a @ in front of a user name to ensure they read your message. Like @WeatherVane. That sends them a ping.

Comment: Wat is the significance of the spool? Does it get thrown along with the ball or is it unwound enough that it stays on the ground when the ball is thrown? If it stays on the ground, why even mention it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the "racking bend" which can be used for this purpose. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lu0k1aseUI

You would make a bend on the climbing rope, either by folding the working end onto itself, or by making a bight anywhere on the climbing rope.

Other options would include the icicle hitch or sailor gripping hitch, but  I think that those hitches might come undone over time. If you just want a temporary solution, they might work for you.

I'm still unclear with the thin line you're describing, though. You have a heavy ball one end, and a spool on the other? what's preventing you from using the ball as a working end?

Comment: To answer you last question, the plan is to throw a goodly length of the thin rope (with the ball to make it throwable/directable) without the weight of the heavy rope slowing it in any way. (I've put a lot of ropes over a lot of tree branches.) It gets attached either so far down the thin rope as to have no effect on what the working end of the free rope does, or after the thin rope is over the branch. Either way, not on the working end.

Comment: Welcome to TGO. Kindly improve your answer by providing a good description of the racking bend, or at least several links to different descriptions. The reason is that your one reference could get taken down and we'd be left with nothing but a name.